# How to make a XACML rule for each sub-element in hierarchical XML (EHR example)?

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac

Let's suppose we have the following example of an EHR

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<ehr id="BH13325600">
    <personalInfo>
        <patientId > PI-33181CRA </patientId>
        <name> Smith Fred </name>
        <birthdate > 07/01/1962 </birthdate>
        <driverL> S350-000-4434 </driverL>
        <p_email> smith.f@domain.net </p_email>
        <gender> Male </gender>
        <address> 166 Hortaon Ave </address>
        <city> GR </city>
        <state> Michigan </state>
        <postCode> 49008 </postCode>
    </personalInfo>
    <healthInfo>    
        <summaryOVisit> 
            Mr. Smith  is 53 years-old MALE who presents complaining for breathing for the past Bla Bla 
        </summaryOVisit>
        <diagnosis>  diagnosed with both knees inflammation 
        </diagnosis>
        <physicianNotes > The patient has diabetes and hypertension  
        </physicianNotes>
        <labResults> Glucose     H107   74-100    mg/dL,     
                     Ca          10.1   8.6-10.2  mg/dL, 
                     BUN         17     8-23      mg/dL, 

        </labResults>
        <medicationInfo> Lipitor 20 MG Oral Tablet,

        </medicationInfo>
        <accountInfo> Active since 08/22/2008, referred by Dr. Jeff Peterson  </accountInfo>    
    </healthInfo>
    <billingInfo> 
        <name> Smith Fred </name>
        <birthdate> 07/01/1962 </birthdate>
        <sSN> 888-888-8888</sSN>
        <healthInsPolicyNo> JXE2346620 </healthInsPolicyNo>
        <paymentType> CCard </paymentType>
        <cardNumber> 0000-0000-0000-0000 </cardNumber>
        <address> 166 Hortaon Ave </address>
        <city> GR</city>
        <state> Michigan </state>
    </billingInfo>
</ehr>
```

This is a request from Surgeon to access the EHR (the surgeon wants to access all EHR including all subelements)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request 
xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"
xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17 
http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-core-v3-schema-wd-17.xsd"
ReturnPolicyIdList="false"
CombinedDecision="false">
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id">
            <AttributeValue DataType="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:data-type:rfc822Name">
                mjack@ces.dh.com <!-- Surgeon-->
            </AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI">
                file://data/SmithFred/EHR <!-- location of Patient's EHR -->
            </AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
                read <!-- Access Actions-->
            </AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Request>
```

Before going to the policy: Q1: Do you think I miss something in the Request? if so please let me know.

I proposed a varible value TVT that should be the trust value thresould for each subelement (record) of EHR, and there is TV (trust value) for the surgeon. the surgoen will be able to access any record in EHR when its TV >= TVT for the record.
So according to your recommendation, I have to write rule for each subelement in EHR. I added this rule as a example to make sure I am in the right way:

```xml
    <Rule RuleId="Data Reduction Rule" effect= "Permit">
            <Description>
                Any subject with an e-mail name in the health.network.com can access (read) only records with TV >= TVT.   
            </Description>  
           <Condition>
    <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:integer-greater-than-or-equal">
                        <VariableReference  VariableId= TVT>
                        <Attribute IncludeInResult="false" AttributeId="SSNTV">
                                <Attributevalue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">80<Attributevalue/>
                        </Attribute>
                    </Apply>
            </Condition>
   </Rule>
```

It is kind of long Question, but your feedback is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, David, for editing my question. Please let me know if you have any answer or comment.